# How to evenly scale up measurements in a recipe to meet certain weight by gram?

Tags: statistics, ratio

I have a recipe that has 9 ingredients, with varying weights that produces a total of 191grams.

For example:

```
ingredient   weight(grams)
a              15            
b              10
c              5
d              5
e              145
f              8 
g              1
h              1
i              1
```

I need to scale up the recipe to make total of 120 oz or 3401.94 grams.

How do I calculate a mulitplier for all the ingredients that evenly scales up? Do I divide 191/3401.94?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around - you're scaling the recipe *up*, so your multiplication factor should be *greater* than one. You need to scale by 3401/191, multiplying all your ingredient weights by 17.8.